# PLSQL Cursor For Loop

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, nested-loops

I am attempting to perform a trend analysis in PLSQL using a for loop nested inside of a cursor for loop. The goal is to return an actor between the years (2000-2013) who have acted in at least 8 movies within a 5 year window.

For example, a desired output would be: Wahlberg, Mark played in 10 movies between 2009 and 2013.
Here is the error I receive:
[image]

Here is the code i'm working with so far:

```
DECLARE
    t movie.yr%TYPE;
    actor_id actor.id%TYPE;
    total INTEGER;
    name actor.name%TYPE;
CURSOR c_actor IS
    select *
    from (select actor.name AS name, count(movie.title) AS total
        from actor, movie, casting
        where movie.id = casting.movie_id
        and actor.id = casting.actor_id
        and movie.yr >= 2000 and movie.yr <=2013
        group by actor.name
        order by count(movie.title) DESC)
    where rownum <= 10;
BEGIN
for v_actor in c_actor
LOOP
    for t in 2000 .. 2009
    LOOP
    select name, total
    into name, total
    from actor, movie
    where movie.yr between t and t+4
    and actor_id = v_actor.actor_id
    and total >= 8
    group by name;
       dbms_output.put_line(name||' played in '||total||' movies between '||t||' and '||t+4);
   END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you overcomplicated it. This should work:

```
begin
  for v_actor in (select a.name, count(*) total
                  from actor a join casting c on a.id = c.actor_id
                  join movie m on m.id = c.movie_id
                  where m.yr between 2000 and 2013
                  group by a.name
                  having count(*) >= 8
                 )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_actor.name ||' acted ' || v_actor.total ||' times');
  end loop;
end;
```

---

I think you created a question a couple of hours before (and deleted it), making same mistakes. For example: you created a variable named `total`, and - at the same time - have it in cursor's `select` statement. You want to display value fetched by the cursor, not the variable itself, unless cursor fetches into that variable - but that's done when you explicitly open/fetch from the cursor, not within the cursor `FOR` loop. With it, you use a cursor variable and use it to display those values.

Comment: Thank you for responding, i'm supposed to create a for loop (t in 2000 .. 2009) inside the cursor for loop (v_actor in c_actor)

Answer (score 1):

you dont get `actor_id` in your cursor query.

```
select *
    from 
   (
    select a.name AS name, count(m.title) AS total
      from actor a
      join casting c 
        on a.id = c.actor_id
      join movie m 
        on m.id = c.movie_id
     where m.yr >= 2000 
       and m.yr <=2013
     group by actor.name
     order by count(movie.title) desc 
   )
   where rownum <= 10;
```